# How to keep R and Rnw files separate when R code is complex

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

I want to use `knitr` to generate a dynamic document based on results produced by a long/complex R script.
I have the following requirement:

- The Rnw file only contains latex and short knitr chunks, by short I mean something like

`<<chunk1>>=
plotData <- getData(some,arguments)
somePlottingFunction(plotData)
@`

or

`<<chunk2>>=
plotData <- getData(some,arguments)
xTable(plotData)
@`

I mean I do not want to have large portion of `R` code mixed with `latex`

What I was doing up to now was to execute a `R` script that would leave some `R` objects in the workspace that would then be used and knit.

```
runFunctionAndKnit <- function(){
   source('theRscript.R')
   knit('theRnwFile.Rnw')
}
```

Problem arise when I use very large objects, I just cannot afford to leave temporary objects waiting to be knit at the end of the script (not enough RAM)

I red quickly the [knitr book](https://www.crcpress.com/Dynamic-Documents-with-R-and-knitr/Xie/9781482203530) (about externalisation) but could not find a solution. Can't I do anything else than saving objects to be loaded/knit afterwards (this looks like it is killing the purpose of `knitr`) ?

As an example say I have some R code like this:

```
main <- function(){
   #some stuff on 10s on lines

   ## @knitr chunk1
   # ...
   ## @knitr

   f1 <- function(){
     #some code
     ## @knitr chunk2
     #some stuff I'd like to knit
     ## @knitr
   }
   f1()

   #some other stuff

   ## @knitr chunk3
   # ...
   ## @knitr
}
```

Is there some way of kniting the following `Rnw` file (some R objects might be destroyed because of scope):

`<<chunk1>>=
@
<<chunk2>>=
@
<<chunk3>>=
@`

Comment: Why leave the objects in the workspace? Use `saveRDS` (for single objects) or `save()` (for multiple objects) to write the objects to files and load them as needed in your `knitr` document. You can clean up with `rm()` as you go if memory is an issue. This can be done either beforehand or as part of the knitting process. It's silly to think that to use `knitr` correctly everything must always be done at once - some model fitting routines can take long periods of time and saving the output to be used by a `knitr` document is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Yes, you can note that I said it on the post... is it the best/only way though, it looks a bit weak in the sense that I could almost save pdf of outputs and run latex on the figures afterwards, no need to use knitr then...

Comment: And there is nothing "silly" about wondering what's the correct way to use a complex package like knitr

Comment: If you save the data but include plotting code in the document then adjusting plots is still easy and the plotting code is included in the document. Saving the plots as PDFs loses that flexibility. I think the answer you propose in your question, and I second in my comment, **is a good solution**. The only thing I'm calling "silly" is your dismissal of it as "killing the purpose of knitr". If you want all the code together, have an early code chunk create objects, write them, and clean up the environment, and have subsequent chunk read in the objects they need and clean up after themselves.